# sybase model database is unavailable

Tags: database, model, sybase, sybase-asa

When I go to create a database on sybase 12 via command
`create database solventiisprbm on solventiisprbm_data = 4096 log on solventiisprbm_log = 1024 go`

gives me the following error

> The Model database is unavailable. It is being used to create a new database.

How can I solve it? It seems like it can't create a new database as there is already a creation in progress, but that's not the case. Do you have any ideas? How can you activate and possibly stop the creation of the database?

Thank you

I tried looking with commands

```
dbcc table(model)
sp_helpdb model
```

but I received no useful information

Comment: you've tagged the question as `ASA` (aka SQLAnywhere) but I'm assuming you meant to tag as `ASE`; without more details I'm guessing a previous command (eg, `create/alter database`) was killed/aborted and has left the `model` database locked; it's not clear from your comment what was actually in the `dbcc table(model)` output so fwiw: you can check the lock status via `dbcc traceon(3604) / dbcc dbtable(model)` and look for the current value of `dbt_lock` (`=1` means db is locked); if db is locked you'll need to bounce the ASE instance

Comment: if this was ASE 15/16 you could try `dbcc dbreboot('reboot',model)`; I don't know (with 100% certainty) if it would work in this scenario but it'd be easy enough to check before undergoing a total dataserver reboot

Comment: restart ASE, that should do it.